# metaquery only searching fist number

Tags: php, wordpress

I am searching for everything greater than or equal to a number but the results only takes into account the first digit in the search box.

eg: if searching for 123 it only brings back results where the first digit is 1.

If I change the compare field to `==` it compares the full number and brings back what I search for.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$filter_size_min = isset($_REQUEST['adv_filter_size_min'])? $_REQUEST['adv_filter_size_min'] : '';
if(is_numeric($filter_size_min) && $filter_size_min>=0) {               
    $nr_sizemin = $filter_size_min;             
    $nr_metaquery[] = array(
        'key'       => $nr_initial.'_size',
        'value'     => $nr_sizemin,
        'type'      => 'text',
        'compare'   => '>='
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
type='NUMERIC'
```

Also see this for reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Thanks that has worked. I was almost sure I had tried that.

Comment: Good :) Mark the answer maybe it will help somebody else :)